# how to convert .pdf file to base64 string in swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, upload, swift2, icloud

I have to upload document in swift , I have to do this using the iCloud , so that I can upload file to my server using icloud

Comment: You do not have to convert files to base64 to be able to upload them to iCloud.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3.x**

```
let filePath = ... //URL of the PDF
let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: filePath!)
let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

Comment: the swift doesn't let me to run the app because of file path in the second line of this method

Comment: It's just a variable, you can replace it with your variable. `filePath` is the variable to store the path of a file.

Comment: doesn't let me again because of try I think you have forgot to write catch error @Hemang Shah

Comment: It worked for me, not sure why isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Drag the pdf file to the project or five the path before to hold

```
 let url1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pdffilename without extension", withExtension: "pdf")
    let one1 = NSData(contentsOf: url1!)
    let pdfstring:String = one1!.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    print(pdfstring)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let filePath = "" // real path of the pdf file
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
let fileStream = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) // base64 string
```

Comment: NSData can be encoded to base64 string, so get the NSData from pdf file first, then encode NSData to base64 string.

Answer (score -1):

Where would you pick the file, That file path has to be given:

1. First generate the base64 string you can use it
2. Then generate the bytes

Which one comfortable could use it.

```
do {
    let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: filePath!)
    let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: fileStream, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    body.append(decodeData!)
}
catch { }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Where would you pick the file, That file path has to be given:", and "Which one comfortable could use it"? Could you please use other words to describe what you mean?